# Uploading file to dropbox with python - Token scope error

Tags: python, dropbox

I'm trying to upload files to my dropbox account via python3 running on a raspberry pi. Have created an app on dropbox, linked it to my account and set all the permissions:

Grab from my dropbox account details for my app:

[screen grab of the dropbox settings here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38c68.png)

Here is the really chopped back code that just tries to upload a file, obviously when I run it the token contains the generated one from dropbox for the app.

```
import dropbox

# the source file
filepath = ("/home/pi/Documents/SIFRD061/CurrentVersion/Diagnostics.txt") # located in folder

# target location in Dropbox
#
targetfile = '/test.txt'   

# Create a dropbox object 
token = ""
d = dropbox.Dropbox(token)

# open the file and upload it
with open(filepath, "rb") as f:

    upresult = d.files_upload(f.read(), targetfile, mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode("overwrite"))

print ('Done')
```

this results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/SIFRD061/CurrentVersion/testdbox2.py", line 20, in <module>
    meta = d.files_upload(f.read(), targetfile, mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode("overwrite"))
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dropbox/base.py", line 2865, in files_upload
    f,
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dropbox/dropbox_client.py", line 327, in request
    timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dropbox/dropbox_client.py", line 483, in request_json_string_with_retry
    timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dropbox/dropbox_client.py", line 608, in request_json_string
    raise AuthError(request_id, err)
dropbox.exceptions.AuthError: AuthError('5ffe22986a4d415d9cfed45bdfd609e0', AuthError('missing_scope', TokenScopeError(required_scope='files.content.write')))
```

I can't see where I'm going wrong, any tips much appreciated, I suspect its probably what I've done in the dropbox account or the settings in the app console as the python code is what a lot of posts have as the answer to 'how to upload to dropbox'

Further info, it doesn't like uploading to the root dir, found that via the api explorer but it isn't the cause of this problem.  I can't get the Dropbox api explorer to run either??

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

The 'missing_scope' error indicates that while the app is permitted to use that scope, the particular access token you're using to make the API call does not have that scope granted. Also, be aware that just adding a scope to your app via the App Console does not retroactively grant that scope to existing access tokens.

That being the case, to make any API calls that require that scope, you'll need to get a new access token with that scope.

Comment: If you check out the screen grab of the permissions it shows the app has permissions to read and write content, the token I used was generated after those permissions were set so as far as i can tell it should work.  Just to be sure I went and generated a new token without changing anything in the permissions and it still comes up with that error.  Thanks for your comments, have you got any other insights that I could try ?  I have checked out a couple of your other posts re python and dropbox and will give some of the code in those a try just in case..

Comment: @Richard The permissions shown in the screenshot only show what's granted to the app overall, but any particular access token might only be granted less than those permissions. You mentioned you generated a new access token, but can you double check you've updated your code with that new access token? Updating the permissions on an app or generating a new access token won't affect existing access tokens.